# How do I disable texture filtering?

Tags: materials, texturing, image

I have a model that is simple and uses low-resolution textures. I'd like to be able to disable the texture filtering so that the textures look sharp and pixels stand out.

An ideal answer would explain how to do this in not only the regular 3d view, but also in renders and preferably also in texture previews.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the 3D view go to:

1. User preferences > System.
2. Then under the OpenGL sub header, you will find "MipMaps" make sure that box is unchecked.

For Blender-Internal go to:

1. Texture Buttons.
2. Image Sampling Panel.
3. Toggle `MIP Map` button.

#### Update

As of [blender 2.71](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Cycles#Nodes) texture nodes now have an option to change the interpolation method:

[image: Using Closest will keep the pixels sharp]

Using Closest will keep the pixels sharp.

---

#### Old Answer

For cycles, this is a needed feature. Here's a workaround (32 is the size of the texture) :

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Though some kind of global (not per material) option to disable filtering in renders would also be awesome.

Comment: It's interesting the **Old answer**... I tried to do it with a Blender Internal material to use in Game Engine, but "Separate XYZ" node doesn't exist in that material system. Is there any other way to separate those channels to make that math? (this would be for appling the technique for just one material).

Comment: It's interesting the **Old answer**... I tried to do it with a Blender Internal material to use in Game Engine, but "Separate XYZ" node doesn't exist in that material system. Is there any other way to separate those channels to make that math? (this would be for appling the technique for just one material).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it is possible to do in the 3D view, but I certainly know how to do it in the (Blender Internal) texture settings(I did this in my [Blender Minecraft Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j45i234qgmo&feature=player_detailpage&list=PLz-rYTT-2nIvviJQDOLvFzic9r2WeY9K2#t=382s)).

Steps:

1. Change the filter type to Box
2. Turn off interpolation
3. Turn off mip-map
4. Set the filter size to 0.1(the lowest possible value)

Comment: Thanks. However, this didn't give me perfectly pixellated results. It was close, and not blurry at least, but not pixellated.

Comment: Really? Can I see a screenshot of the render? Can the filter size go any lower?

Comment: I'm not sure I can get this image to work inline correctly in a comment, but I uploaded a gif of the filtering modes. Note that the final unfiltered frame is just the image resized in Photoshop by 1650% using nearest filtering. The original texture is only 128x128, so filtering makes it look terrible. [Blender filtering](http://i.imgur.com/rN4dS7x.gif)

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean. I've always just set the filter size to a really low value. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are asking about rendering and 3d View, but if someone is looking for achieving this in Game Engine using BlenderPlayer command line, you have to run file as:

```
blenderplayer -g nomipmap = 1 file.blend
```

If you want to run game **inside** Blender, the "MipMaps" unchecked in Preferences works (as OwMyWrists said).