# How can I keep low resolution textures pixelated?

Tags: texturing, uv, pixel-art

I have a problem. I am going to make a minecraft animation in blender. But when I put a minecraft texture on a 3d cube that is 16x16x16 it is very low resolution is there a way to get the texture in a better resolution or is there a way to make blender make the texture better?

I hope you have an answer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/760973-how-to-resize-picture-in-gimp-without-getting-blury-picture/

Comment: You go to user prefrences and disable mipmapping.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In addition to scaling the textures up in an image editor with [pixel interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Scaling_methods) disabled, (as [mentioned by Gunslinger](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2588/599))
Another method is to disable pixel interpolation right in Blender and save memory, and as already mentioned by Krivar, keeping the texture sharp even when close up:

## [Cycles:](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles)

---

### Update

As of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBdd2dca2f7e77), ([will be in blender 2.71](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Cycles#Nodes)) texture nodes now have an option to change the interpolation method:

[image]

Using *Closest* will keep the pixels sharp.

---

### Original answer:

You could use [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?244662-Cycles-Getting-rid-of-Texture-Interpolation-yay-for-blocky-no-for-blurry!!) technique, which uses a [node setup](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes) to scale the [UV map](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV):

[image: A variation of the original setup on BA]

- To add [*Nodes*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes), press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Add node* in the [*Node Editor*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Editor).
- To create a [*Node Group*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Node_Editor#Group_Interface), select the nodes you want and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to make them into a group, creating the *Group input* and *Group output* nodes. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle editing the group.
- To use the above group, connect the *UV* output of the *[Texture Coordinates](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Texture_Coordinates) node* to the *UV* input of the *[NodeGroup](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Node_Groups#Grouping_Nodes)*, and connect the output to the UV coordinates used to map your texture.
  (The *Vector* input on the [*texture node*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures#Image_Texture)):

[image: Example setup]

Set the *X* and *Y* values to the *X* and *Y* dimensions of your texture.

## [Blender Internal:](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render)

Disable *Interpolation* and set *filter* to *Box* in [*Material texture settings > Image Sampling*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Types/Image#Image_Sampling):

[image: No interpolation BI settings]

## [Viewport](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View)

You can disable interpolation in the Viewport by disabling [*Mipmaps*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/System#Open_GL) in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*→ [User Preferences](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences) → [System](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/System)*:

[image: Mipmapping disabled]

Comment: The only thing I did understand is the picture in the bottom. I am kinda beginner in blender. I don't know how to open group input or texture coordinate. But it seems to work very good for @WChargin and krivar so I think its a good answer if I understand it.

Comment: @joapet99 I have updated my answer with more detail, hope this helps :)

Comment: Is this nodes applied to the texture or the material with the texture

Comment: @joapet99 these are [Material nodes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes). (So the material with the texture)

Note that if you are using [Blender Internal render](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render), you don't have to worry about the nodes, You only need those if you are using [Cycles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles).

Answer (score 5):

Scale the texture to 512x512 in your favourite image editing software. Set interpolation to nearest, this is important.

Here is how it is done in photoshop:

[image: Image size in photoshop]

Gandalfs answer is IMO the right one.

Comment: the answer by Gandalf is better, as you keep the tiny texture size. Also the textures will keep sharp even in extreme conditions.

Comment: Using GIMP. In the interpolation section you can choose between: None, Linear, Cubic, Sinc(Lanczos3).

Comment: None seems reasonable. But as everyone poits out, follow gandalfs answer.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't exist a direct way to do this in Cycles yet it seems. However, a user on the ba forums has devised a node group for this, see [Cycles: Getting rid of Texture Interpolation](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?244662-Cycles-Getting-rid-of-Texture-Interpolation-yay-for-blocky-no-for-blurry!!&p=2303364&viewfull=1#post2303364), it has an attached example blend.

[image]

For the 3d view, see [How do I disable texture filtering?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/845/how-do-i-disable-texture-filtering?rq=1).