# Can ultra-low-res textures cause problems while rendering?

Tags: rendering, texturing

This is a strange question, so comment if it's unclear.

I'm making a low-poly piece of art, where many of my objects will have only a single flat color (a cube that's all green, for example).

It seems that I should be able to use a very small texture for each object (the green cube could use just a single green pixel as its texture, for example).

I want to know if this will cause any problems. Should I use 16x16 or 32x32 textures, even though they provide more resolution than I actually need?

I am using the Blender internal render engine, though I also plan to export to Unity for a game project.

Comment: What render engine are you using?  I don't see any way it could cause problems for Cycles.  But if you have something that is all one color why do you even need a texture for it?

Comment: A lot of the objects are made by merging several single-color objects together into one, multi-color object. Can I do that without textures?

Comment: Sure, you can have multiple materials on one object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I keep low resolution textures pixelated?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/how-can-i-keep-low-resolution-textures-pixelated)

Comment: @HATMAN I don't see how that's a duplicate.  That's talking about color interpolation on scaled up low res textures, this is asking if there are problems with using very small textures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, having a low res texture can cause issues, but they can be prevented. Here is an example:**

This is the texture I will be using in the example, which is 16x16 pixels:

[image: WaterTexture]

If we import this into Blender we notice that the pixels are all smoothed and the detail is completely lost. This is because the interpolation is set to *Linear*, which will fade from the color of one vertex to the next using a linear gradient:

[image: Linear]

Switching this to *Closest* brings back all the detail and makes the image remain sharp:

[image: Closest]

In your particular example, as long as this is enabled, you can go down to a 1 pixel size without any issues.

Comment: I don't think you experience this effect if the texture is a solid color.

Comment: @PGmath I was under the impression they wanted to use ***1*** texture to define all the colors