# How do I stop textures from blurring when rendering small images

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

EDIT: This question is different from [How can I keep low resolution textures pixelated?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/how-can-i-keep-low-resolution-textures-pixelated) because I am not rendering a low-resolution texture into a high resolution image. I am rendering a high resolution texture into a low resolution image. The same solution to that question does not apply here. This is what the texture looks like:

[image]

I was hoping to use Blender to render sprites for a little game I am making. I started working on tiles and I noticed something weird.

In this example image, the left half is just a stretched out plane that has UV mapping to a texture. The right half is a completely separate object using the same material/texture, except that it is not UV mapped. You will notice that I am getting a pretty weird effect. Here is the un-edited raw rendered .png that I got from blender:

[image: Wall Tile Rendered]

On the left half, the image is being blurred, blended, interpolated(?). The right side without the UV mapping seems confused, part of it is blurred but on the far right the image remains pixelated! The next image is blown up preserving the pixelation so it is easier to see:

[image]

Is there a way to intentionally get this effect? I tried turning off interpolation but that didn't seem to do the trick. After looking through the settings and googling around, I don't see anyone else having this problem.
Note: Right now I am not using material/texture nodes. I am still a blender noob and not sure how to set those up let alone do advanced things with them...yet.

If there is an easy solution that does not require nodes, can I please have that solution first?

If I cannot avoid using nodes, would someone mind helping guide me to how I may get this done with the use of nodes?

Comment: So which effect would you like to get intentionally ? Weirdness on the right object happens because it isn't UV unwrapped. It either should has UV map or use some other coordinates for texture (e.g. Flat if that's plane).

Comment: @David You marked this question as duplicate. Can you direct me to the question that this one is duplicating?

All the questions that I found are rendering low resolution textures at high quality. This is the other way around, a high quality texture being rendered at a very low resolution, and the same solutions no longer apply here. So please, help me find an answer?

Comment: @David I found at the top which question this is a duplicate of. The solution for that question does not apply here. I edited my question to explain why.

Comment: In this case you should consider reviewing the title of the question. Now it states "how do I *stop* textures from blurring", which is the case of question linked as a duplicate.

Comment: @StevenRogers ok, I see now. Good edit. (PS when a question is marked as a duplicate the link to the other question is always at the top.)

Comment: @Steven, Can you show the current configuration (or let the blend file to download)?