# In version 2.77 how do I view textures in different interpolation modes from viewport?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

Recently I updated my blender to 2.77a and annoyingly I noticed that the interpolation mode selection from the image texture node no longer takes effect in the texture mode at viewport.

Is this function simply removed or now I have to have it activated somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Disabling [mip-mapping in user-preferences](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2589/599) works, but is admittedly a rather clumsy workaround.

Comment: I knew I can do that but unfortunately for me it's not remotely close to a workaround since a lot of times I have lots of textures that need to be in different interpolation mode and I rely on 3d viewport to check whether they are properly interpolated. I'm just gonna send a feedback to blender.org. Thank you for you help.