# Pixelated textures blurred in Render view?

Tags: rendering, texturing

So, my problem is that I'm using a pixelated texture with a model. I've followed the directions for disabling MipMaps and Interpolations so the texture and material both preserve the pixelation, but this doesn't hold up when Rendering.

In material/texture view I get the pixelation I want, but when in render view, the texture is blurred again.

Is there something in render settings or filtering that I'm missing?

[image: for instance]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/how-can-i-keep-low-resolution-textures-pixelated

Comment: @cegaton I've seen this question and many other that have been answered with it. But disabling mipmaps and interpolation in Blender still doesn't change whatever is happening in the render view