# Textures are not sharp when rendering

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

This is how my Textures look in Default Mode:

[image]

and this is how they look in Render mode: 
[image]

how can i get my textures in Render Mode as sharp as they are in Default Mode?

I've Read that you can change the interpolation of textures somewhere, but i can't find them. I'm using Blender 2.79b.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2586/36012

Comment: @yann how can i this "Image Texture"-window? I can't find it?!

Comment: That depends whether you are using cylces or blender internal. In cycles you find the option you are looking for directly on the node that imports your image (open a node-editor and make sure "use nodes" is checked and your material is selected. Find your image texture node and change the filter mode). In blender internal, you find this option in the "Texture" properties tab, sub menu "Image sampling". I noticed that all links to the documentation are broken in @gandalf3 answer. But the naming didn't change, so you can search for the respective sections in the 2.79 documentation.

Comment: I overlooked your tags. Since you are using blender-internal, navigate to the texture panel (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/texture_panel.html), select the texture in the list you want to modify and scroll down to "filter". Like in gandalfs answer: uncheck "interpolation" and set your filter to "box". Here is the 2.79 doc page for texture filtering and image sampling: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/types/image/options.html#image-sampling