# different brush strokes via texture painting

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to paint textures for my models in semi-pixelart style, so i use pixelate brush
texture projection is on Flat mode, brush stroke is in constant mode
you can see on screenshot left blot is painted on model itself and the right one painted on texture image and it have some antialiasing. how to paint on texture itself without AA?[image]

Comment: Partly here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/how-can-i-keep-low-resolution-textures-pixelated