# Why Are There Glowing White Lines Around My Minecraft Rig?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm really bad at blender, so my mistake might be the simplest, but I have a few glowing lines around my Minecraft rig and blocks. [image: Glowing white lines around my rig.] Here's the blender file: [My .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw1OxK_VqKLLNUR6WWp4WTgwS3M) 
If this helps, my rendering engine is on Cycles Render.

Comment: Search for the Addon McPrep, which optimizes textures from different minecraft eporters for cycles/render internal

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be resolved by setting the texture interpolation to Nearest Neighbour. This gives you that pixelated Minecraft look too. See [the answer to this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/845/888) for more info in how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your blend file. As it seems, all your textures are linked to one image with many square-like texture images which are VERY low resolution and with transparency. As far as I figure, the white lines come from smoothing from the texture color to the transparent parts of the texture. This always happens, but it is very pronounced as your textures have such a low resolution (I guess something like 32x32 pixels or so)

I suggest that you create textures with higher resolution and replace your low res texture images with high res ones.